# how to enable top level await in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have installed craco
using `yarn add @craco/craco`
I have also replaced the scritps
and have created a craco.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    webpack: {
        experiments: {
            topLevelAwait: true
        }
    }
}
```

but when I'm trying to use await at top level
I'm still getting this error in my react app

```
ERROR in ./src/Enforcer.js

Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
    at /home/shivansh/Desktop/dev/os-2/casbin-core/test/reactjs/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyDetectionParserPlugin.js:54:11
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/home/shivansh/Desktop/dev/os-2/casbin-core/test/reactjs/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:7:16)
    at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (/home/shivansh/Desktop/dev/os-2/casbin-core/test/reactjs/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:14:14)
    at JavascriptParser.walkAwaitExpression (/home/shivansh/Desktop/dev/os-2/casbin-core/test/reactjs/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:2337:29)
    at JavascriptParser.walkExpression (/home/shivansh/Desktop/dev/os-2/casbin-core/test/reactjs/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:2267:10)
    at JavascriptParser.walkVariableDeclaration (/home/shivansh/Desktop/dev/os-2/casbin-core/test/reactjs/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:2121:33)
    at JavascriptParser.walkStatement (/home/shivansh/Desktop/dev/os-2/casbin-core/test/reactjs/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:1615:10)
    at JavascriptParser.walkStatements (/home/shivansh/Desktop/dev/os-2/casbin-core/test/reactjs/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:1476:9)
    at JavascriptParser.parse (/home/shivansh/Desktop/dev/os-2/casbin-core/test/reactjs/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:3370:9)
    at /home/shivansh/Desktop/dev/os-2/casbin-core/test/reactjs/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:1087:26
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `craco` docs, it says you [need to add a `configure` block](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco/README.md#configuration-file) to handle any [webpack configuration options](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/experiments/#experiments)

`

What happens if you change

```
module.exports = {
    webpack: {
        experiments: {
            topLevelAwait: true
        }
    }
}
```

to

```
module.exports = {
      // ...
      webpack: {
        configure: {
          experiments: {
              topLevelAwait: true
          }
        }
      }
}
```