# Redux Configure Store with async preloadState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am having the following problem setting up my redux store in a react app with preloadedState: I am relying on data from an async function. I tried to solve it with top level await, but I couldn't enable it via the webpack.config.js file ([how to enable top level await in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72554567/how-to-enable-top-level-await-in-reactjs)).

my first question is if react (^18.2.0) supports top level await?

my second question is if there is a workaround to my problem?

```
async function preloadState() {
  const selectionState = await window.browser.storage.local.get("selectionState");
  const externalTimings = await window.browser.storage.local.get("externalTimings");
  return {
    'selectionState': selectionState,
    'externalTimings': externalTimings
  }
}


export const store = configureStore({
  preloadedState: preloadState(),
  reducer: {
    selectionState: selectionStateSliceReducer,
    externalTimings: externalTimingsReducer,
  },
})
```